# Как сделать запрос на сайт, через прокси?

Tags: c#

Добрый день! Хотел бы проверить на сайте счетчик посетителей. У меня есть несколько прокси и я хотел сделать небольшую программку для входа на сайт, под разными прокси.

```
public void Webrequest(string url, string proxy)
        {
            try {
                var request = WebRequest.Create(url);
                WebProxy proxyObject = new WebProxy(proxy, true);
                proxyObject.BypassProxyOnLocal = false;
                request.Proxy = proxyObject;

            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
            }

        }
```

Но она не работает, все равно использует при запросе мой IP адрес.

Answer (score 1):

Обратите внимание на это чудо https://github.com/X-rus/xNet.
Для вас в самый раз.
Пример запроса с Proxy:

```
HttpRequest request =  new HttpRequest();
request.UserAgent = Http.ChromeUserAgent();
request.Proxy = HttpProxyClient.Parse("127.0.0.1:1080");
string responce = request.Get("http://site.com/").ToString();
request.Close();
```

Однако, если вам таки нужно стандартными средствами, то, например, так:

```
public void Webrequest(string url, string proxy)
{
    try {
        var request = WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Proxy = new System.Net.WebProxy {
        Address = new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:8080")
        };
    //тут логика работы с http...

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
    }

}
```

Обратите внимание, что так же существуют прокси с паролем или Socks. Удачи!